# I want to pass o/p of following line into controller ie <?php echo $module[$i]->im_name; ?>

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

This is my code :

```
if (count($template) >=1) { ?>  

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col" id="select">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">select <?php echo $module[$i]->im_name; ?> Template</h2>
              </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__media">
                <?php echo $template[0]->iut_tempname; ?>

            </div>

            <a href="<?php echo base_url("Account/template_list/"); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>  

    <?php

        }
```

I want to pass o/p of this im_name; ?> to controller .

Comment: read docs https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I read but not found any solution for this.... if any other suggestion...thanks

Comment: what do you want , uplaod a file using form or load only view ? pls clear

Comment: upload a file in view directory

Comment: show your full code what u have tried?

Comment: Why you want to upload files in view directory?

Comment: plz check nd give some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Create a folder `uploads` in your views folder and use `VIEWPATH` for the `upload_path` like this :

```
$config['upload_path']  = VIEWPATH.'uploads/';
```

Your code should be like this :

```
if (isset($_FILES["image_file"]["name"])) 
{

    $config['upload_path']  = VIEWPATH.'uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types']= 'txt|php|html';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file')) 
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        echo '<img src="'.base_url().'uploads/'.$data["file_name"].'" />';  
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: thanks now its working but now it allow only html file not php

Comment: so u want to say that i give an answer to you that is why its stops working for html file ,pls post next question for this error , my answer solves ur current problem if it helps u pls don't hesitate to check it as green